# What to do with JSON text output?

Tags: php, jquery, json, rest

I'm working with an API for the first time.  Using cURL, I can get a token from the API and use it to get a response in JSON-formatted text.  Here's my code:

```
<?php
$host = 'HOST';
$username = 'USERNAME';
$password = 'PASSWORD';
$payloadName = 'grant_type=client_credentials';
$process = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payloadName);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$return = curl_exec($process);
$str = ''.$return.'';
$start  = strpos($str, '{');
$end    = strpos($str, '}', $start - 1);
$length = $end - $start;
$json = substr($str, $start - 1, $length + 2);


$results = json_decode($json, true);
$token = $results['access_token'];
$type = $results['token_type'];


$curl = curl_init( "API URL?fields=title,author" );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token) );
$return2 = curl_exec( $curl );

?>
```

My problem is that decoding the JSON for the token seemed to work fine, but the value of $return2 is just "1" or "true", so there's nothing to parse if I use the same method.

This is outputting a text result of, for example:

> {"id":xxxxxx,"title":"War dogs","author":"Bear, Greg, 1951-"}

to the webpage, so how do I capture what is being output into a variable that I can work with, either server-side, or client-side?

Comment: Use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: @dave - that's ruby, not PHP ;-)

Comment: @dbinns66 umm, no, that's JavaScript

Comment: @dave - LOL works GREAT in ruby ;-)  I sit corrected...

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a native Javascript notation. In fact it stands for "JavaScript Object Notation". For example,

```
var jsonobj = {"id":123456,"title":"War dogs","author":"Bear, Greg, 1951-"};
```

Is valid JS. And it will produce an object you can work with.

```
alert(jsonobj.title); //alerts "War Dogs"
```

How you get a variable set, I am not sure based on your example. If the variable `$json` is available to you in the HTML portion of a PHP file, in a `<script>` section you can do:

```
var jsonobj = <?php echo $json; ?>;
```

Comment: As a sidenote it is better to json_decode the result and escape it again when outputting with json_encode. This would fix any potential security issue arising from a bad service response.